# How to reference a Value in .Open "Get" statement Statment in VBA

Tags: vba

I got referenced value in my sub, but I want to use my referenced value within the GET statement.
I want to use my num1 value as my destaination = in my .Open "Get" statement.

```
 Dim num1 As String
 Set htm = CreateObject("htmlFile")
 num1 = Cells(2, 2).Value
 With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
    .Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=sy10 5tp&destinations='num1'&mode=driving&language=en-GB&v=3&sensor=fals", False
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the quoted string literal with `"` and use the `&` concatenation operator to append the variable:

```
x = "abc" & stringVariable & "def"
```

So

```
.Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=sy10 5tp&destinations=" & num1 & "&mode=driving&language=en-GB&v=3&sensor=fals", False
```

(You also have `fals` which presumably should be `false`)